How to fix this issue , entry-server.tsx:6:5: ERROR: Expected ")" but found "?" , /entry-client.tsx:7:34: ERROR: Expected ")" but found "as"
Im trying to migrate a existing react js app built using cra , to vite ssr . I have installed all the dep packages and moved all the code . while im trying to run the project using npm run dev . I end up getting this issue
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
D:/Practise/vitessrmicrosite/src/entry-server.tsx:6:5: ERROR: Expected ")" but found "?"
    at failureErrorWithLog (D:\Practise\vitessrmicrosite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1472:15)
    at D:\Practise\vitessrmicrosite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:755:50
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (D:\Practise\vitessrmicrosite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:622:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (D:\Practise\vitessrmicrosite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:677:12)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (D:\Practise\vitessrmicrosite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:600:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:545:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:495:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:375:5)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)

this is my entry-server.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { RenderToPipeableStreamOptions, renderToPipeableStream } from 'react-dom/server';
import App from './App';

export function render(
  url?: string, // Optional parameter
  ssrManifest?: any,
  options?: RenderToPipeableStreamOptions
) {
  return renderToPipeableStream(
    <App />,
    options
  );
}

this is my entry-client.tsx
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement,

        <App />
     
);

this is my server.js
import fs from 'node:fs/promises'
import express from 'express'
import { Transform } from 'node:stream'

// Constants
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 5173
const base = process.env.BASE || '/'
const ABORT_DELAY = 10000

// Cached production assets
const templateHtml = isProduction
  ? await fs.readFile('./dist/client/index.html', 'utf-8')
  : ''
const ssrManifest = isProduction
  ? await fs.readFile('./dist/client/.vite/ssr-manifest.json', 'utf-8')
  : undefined

// Create http server
const app = express()

// Add Vite or respective production middlewares
let vite
if (!isProduction) {
  const { createServer } = await import('vite')
  vite = await createServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
    appType: 'custom',
    base
  })
  app.use(vite.middlewares)
} else {
  const compression = (await import('compression')).default
  const sirv = (await import('sirv')).default
  app.use(compression())
  app.use(base, sirv('./dist/client', { extensions: [] }))
}

// Serve HTML
app.use('*', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const url = req.originalUrl.replace(base, '')

    let template
    let render
    if (!isProduction) {
      // Always read fresh template in development
      template = await fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8')
      template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template)
      render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule('/src/entry-server.tsx')).render
    } else {
      template = templateHtml
      render = (await import('./dist/server/entry-server.js')).render
    }

    let didError = false

    const { pipe, abort } = render(url, ssrManifest, {
      onShellError() {
        res.status(500)
        res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
        res.send('<h1>Something went wrong</h1>')
      },
      onShellReady() {
        res.status(didError ? 500 : 200)
        res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })

        const transformStream = new Transform({
          transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            res.write(chunk, encoding)
            callback()
          }
        })

        const [htmlStart, htmlEnd] = template.split(`<!--app-html-->`)

        res.write(htmlStart)

        transformStream.on('finish', () => {
          res.end(htmlEnd)
        })

        pipe(transformStream)
      },
      onError(error) {
        didError = true
        console.error(error)
      }
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      abort()
    }, ABORT_DELAY)
  } catch (e) {
    vite?.ssrFixStacktrace(e)
    console.log(e.stack)
    res.status(500).end(e.stack)
  }
})

// Start http server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

this is my package.json
{
  "name": "vitessrmicrosite",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "build:client": "vite build --ssrManifest --outDir dist/client",
    "build:server": "vite build --ssr src/entry-server.tsx --outDir dist/server",
    "preview": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@fontsource/krub": "^4.5.10",
    "@fontsource/teko": "^4.5.9",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.11",
    "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^8.1.0",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.18.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "htmlparser2": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-debounce-input": "^3.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^3.1.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-simple-captcha": "^9.0.17",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-us-state-map": "^1.0.1",
    "react-usa-map": "^1.5.0",
    "sirv": "^2.0.4",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "validator": "^13.9.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.5",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.6",
    "@types/react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4",
    "vite": "^5.2.10"
  }
}

this is my tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

this is my vite.config.json
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  esbuild: {
    loader: 'jsx', // Enable JSX parsing for all supported file extensions
    include: [ // Explicitly include common JSX extensions for clarity
    
      "src/**/*.jsx",
      "src/**/*.tsx",
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': '/src', // Example alias, adjust as needed
    },
  },
  
  
});

Tried some online resources which said  to configure vite config file and ts config file , still I'm not able to fix that issue, I'm trying to run this project with ssr features enabled
